# Is there a way to remove gpg sign of all previous commits or resign it with another gpg key

Tags: git, gnupg

I have just lost my old gpg key by accident. I'm wondering if I can remove each commit's gpg sign or resign it with my new gpg key?

Comment: have you tried `git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -S <keyid>` ?

Comment: Yeah, It gave me this error. error: pathspec 'xxxxxxxx' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: You will need to replace each old commit with a new one: the new hash IDs will differ. @julian's command should work for this but note that it is `-S<keyid>` with no space; `-S <keyid>` is treated as `-S`, i.e., no key-ID specified, and then the keyid argument is treated as a file name (which gets you the pathspec error).

Comment: Thank you for helping. It seems like the command only change one commit. Is there something like a batch process?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but i came across a similiar situation where i had to sign(re-sign actually) bunch of old commits.
First confirm how many of the previous commits you want to (re)sign:

```
git log --show-signature
```

Suppose you want to sign the previous 5 commits then you can do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

In the editor you will see your commits:

```
...
pick 4dd9ec5 fixed wrong config
pick 89d21f4 minor fix
...
```

Just add this line after every commit that you want to sign(re-sign).

```
exec git commit --amend --no-edit -s
```

So it would look like :

```
...
pick 4dd9ec5 fixed wrong config
exec git commit --amend --no-edit -s
pick 89d21f4 minor fix
exec git commit --amend --no-edit -s
...
```

Save and exit:

NOTE: Make sure you have force push priviledge (git push -f) in the upstream repository  because this most likely would require to push with all force.

ANOTHER NOTE:
With this method you can sign all but one previous commit. You may not be able to sign your initial commit.

[Source](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/sdk/en/latest/docs/contributors/signing-commits.html)

Comment: Regarding your last comment: Doesn't `git rebase --root` allow that?